# WSO2 API Manager WSDL Endpoint

Tags: wsdl, endpoint

I am trying to Expose a WSDL in WSO2 API Manager, by selecting WSDL Endpoint in the Implementation tab.
And providing the service name and Port respectively.

But while testing the same, from Api Store, the response is 0 - No response body. Also the WSDL is not being invoked.

Please help with this. 
I have checked many blogs and videos, but can't find exact solution.

Ex WSDL that I am using is: https://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl

Answer (score 0):

Used the same wsdl and expose the service using api manager and got the response from the web server. But as per the query  posted above you are testing the soap service using api store. There may be mismatch the param you are posting to web service. Therefore use tool like soapUI to test the web service.

User the followings while exposing the SOAP Service

```
SOAP WSDL - https://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx?wsdl
SOAP Endpoint - https://ws.cdyne.com/phoneverify/phoneverify.asmx
```

Reference -

[1] http://blog.rajkumarr.com/2015/08/how-to-expose-soap-services-as-soap-services-via-wso2-api-manager.html

[2] http://www.vitharana.org/2015/01/soap-web-service-as-rest-api-using-wso2.html

[3] https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM191/Invoke+an+API+using+a+SOAP+Client